# Pull files concurrently using single SFTP connection in Java - Improving SFTP performance

Tags: java, performance, sftp, jsch

I need to pull the files concurrently from remote server using single SFTP connection in Java code.

I've already got few links to pull the files one by one on single connection.
Like:

To use `sftpChannel.ls("Path to dir");` which will returns list of files in the given path as a vector and you have to iterate on the vector to download each file `sftpChannel.get();`

But I want to pull multiple files concurrently for eg. 2 files at a time on single connection.

Thank You!

Comment: Why? I'm afraid you have some ungrounded performance expectations from this. You still use one connection, it won't be faster than downloading the files sequentially. Unless the bottleneck is the local or remote drive (what is unlikely) and you want to optimize the transfer by reading/writing to/from multiple drives.

Comment: @Martin: Why I want to pull files concurrently? : Is to improve performance & we've only single connection. So, is there any way to pull files concurrently. Using any other API or any other solution to this ?

Comment: Again, why do you think that concurrent download over a single connection will improve performance?

Comment: *is there any way to pull files concurrently*: My answer shows that.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve performance improvement while pulling files or pull files concurrently as we've only single connection ? Any API or Thread mechanism ?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [`ChannelSftp.get` method](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#get-java.lang.String-) returns an [`InputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html).

So you can call the `get` multiple times, acquiring a stream for each download. And then keep polling the streams until all reach the end-of-file.

Though I do not see, what advantage this gives you over a sequential download.

---

If you want to improve performance, you first need to know, what is the bottleneck.

The typical bottlenecks are:

- Network speed: If you are saturating the network speed already, you cannot improve anything.
- Network latency: If the latency is the bottleneck, increasing size of an SFTP request queue may help. Use the [`ChannelSftp.setBulkRequests` method](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#setBulkRequests-int-) (the default is 16, so use a higher number)
- CPU: If the CPU is the bottleneck, you either have to improve efficiency of the encryption implementation, or spread the load across CPU cores. Spreading the encryption load of a single session/connection is tricky and would have to be supported on low-level SSH implementation. I do not think JSch or any other implementation supports that.
- Disk: If a disk drive (local or remote) is the bottleneck (unlikely), the parallel transfers as shown above may help, even when using a single connection, if the parallel transfers use a different disk drive each.

For more in-depth information, see my answers to:

- [Why is FileZilla SFTP file transfer max capped at 1.3MiB/sec instead of saturating available bandwidth? rsync and WinSCP are even slower](https://serverfault.com/q/694062/168875)
- [Why is FileZilla so much faster than PSFTP?](https://serverfault.com/q/700780/168875)